# hosted Laravel not storing images but works perfectly on localhost

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have a Laravel project hosted in CPanel and it’s running but when I upload an image, it supposed to store in the public folder like ("public_path()/posts/theactualimage.jpeg").

in my local machine things are going pretty well but not on the hosted

I don’t know if there’s any configuration that I should do …

here is the structure of the folders

```
./
|    public_html
|    |    posts
|    |    index.php 
|    |    some other files
|
|    myapp
|    |    all the other files controllers views
```

## here is the function that stores the images

```
public function uploadImage($location, $imageName){
    $name = $imageName->getClientOriginalName();
    $imageName->move(public_path().'/'.$location, date('ymdgis').$name);
    return date('ymdgis').$name;
}
```

**the uploaded image is automatically creating new folder inside myapp/public/posts/(image.jpg)**

Comment: Did you check if the path has write permissions for the webserver? The path is read only by default on most servers.

Comment: Where can i find it can u guide it through? I am new to this. Thankyou

Comment: Check with your FTP client the properties of `myapp/public/posts`, you should be able to set write permissions. Give the folder write permissions for `others`. This will give the webserver user rights to write new files to the folder.

Comment: Check this page for more info: https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ftp/change-permissions/ Only edit the write permissions, leave all other settings alone and the way they are.

Answer (score 0):

if possible please log the public path and location, see if you getting expected results

Comment: Its working perfectly on localhost.. i cannot log in hosting 

Comment: You can, check the logs folder on the root folder